# Using a .pch file of static library in other project

Tags: ios, static-libraries

How can I use a .pch file of a static library in another project,which is using the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project build settings, search for "pch".

There will be an item "Prefix Header" where you should enter the name of your PCH file.